# simply sql boolean condition

Tags: sql

I need to check if a value lies in a range, however I can't guarantee that either end of the range isn't `NULL`. The values in this case are integers. '`mo`' represents employment

currently I have the following

```
WHERE (r.year BETWEEN mo.startyear AND mo.endyear >= r.year) 
OR (mo.startyear <= r.year AND mo.endyear IS null)
OR (mo.startyear IS null AND mo.endyear IS null)
OR (mo.startyear IS null AND mo.endyear >= r.year)
```

is this the only way to check the `mo` was 'employed' at a particular year (`r`)

Comment: sorry I should have stipulated that this needs to be ANSI SQL. Maybe it's not possible to simply this further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
WHERE ( mo.startyear <= r.year OR mo.startyear IS NULL )
  AND ( mo.endyear >= r.year OR mo.endyear IS NULL )
```

Comment: Perfect, if it wasn't 4am I might have got here without your help, but many thanks indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Set a default value for the NULLs. If you are using Oracle then something like:

```
WHERE r.year
BETWEEN nvl(mo.startyear,to_date('01/01/1990','dd/mm/yyyy'))
AND nvl(mo.endyear,to_date('31/12/4701','dd/mm/yyyy'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE r.year BETWEEN(COALESCE(mo.startyear,-9999) AND COALESCE(mo.endyear,9999))
```

COALESCE first tries the first argument and if it is null it goes for the next one. So, unless your years are less than -9999 or over 9999, this will work. Otherwise, increase those numbers :) It is also ansi standard

PS: This is dirty indeed, but it is the most compact form I can think of